# Get selected component in Fastreport editor?

Tags: delphi, vcl, fastreport

Is there any way of getting the object/component the user selects on the report's editor? I mean, is there any way of Delphi application being aware of which item/object/component has been selected?

for instance, if I click on a TfrxMemoView or TfrxPictureView I would like my Delphi app to identify that object so that you can work with it, something like this...

```
myMemo := myDesigner.getSelected;
```

or

```
myMemo := myReport.getSelected;
```

I am using FastReports VCL 6.

If you know how to achieve that it would be pretty helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, in case you need to do the same as I needed, I managed to do so by this:

```
for I := 0 to Report.Designer.SelectedObjects.Count - 1 do
    begin
     ShowMessage(TfrxComponent(Report.Designer.SelectedObjects.Items[i]).Name);
      if TfrxComponent(Report.Designer.SelectedObjects.Items[i]) is TfrxMemoView then
       begin
         TfrxMemoView(Report.Designer.SelectedObjects.Items[i]).Align:= baLeft;
         Report.Designer.ReloadObjects();{to refresh the designer as it was embedded in a panel and I wanted to change components properties on "realtime"}
       end;
    end;
```